# where to put the text file in web application

Tags: java, jsf, web-applications

I have email manager and I load the email contents from the text files. I load the text files from the class path. When I test in the java SE environment, it works well. When I used the email Manager in web application, I got the `FileNotFoundException`. I would like to know where can I put the text files to load successfully in web application?

**Edit**

In the email manager,

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("EmailContent.txt");
```

[image: Project structure]

Comment: generally the environment puts everything in the classpath, with your web app you need to tell it to be put into WEB-INF

Comment: I put txt file into the WEB-INF but I still got the FileNotFoundException.

Comment: can you show us your deployment structure? (where the file you are calling from is and where the file you want is?)

Answer (score -1):

WebContent should be the right place without defining a path works on tomcat